# Do you know how to mark lines in VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to differentiate lines in my VBA code, especially pair commands. I try to cascade them, but despite my effort sometimes I get lost which pair code belongs to/where it ends, when I have more cycles in other cycles. Is there any way to mark lines by colour? So I could distungish pair commands by colour?

Thank you.

Jake

Comment: I'd suggest you get an indenting tool like Smart Indenter, and get into the habit of writing the closing block immediately after you write the starting block.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, but the majority of people use 32bit Office. :)

Comment: We use 64bit, I Will try Rubberduck, Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested, use an indenter to enforce consistent indentation. Several VBIDE add-ins exist that provide this functionality, including the original Smart Indenter (free, 32-bit only) and [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (free, open-source, works in 64-bit hosts, too - I'm a contributor).

#### Write Smaller Procedures

Procedures that do *as little as needed* to fulfill the promise made by their name. Procedures that do one thing usually do it well, and are pretty easy to name meaningfully.

If you have a nested loop, the inner loop can be extracted into its own scope. If the nested loop has a conditional, each conditional branch can be refactored and extracted into its own scope. The likely result is that you end up *deleting redundant code*, because a lot of times what you pull out of one branch is very similar to what you pull out of another branch, save a few parameter values that, once refactored, become actual parameters; procedures become smaller, more specialized, they do so little that naming them is trivial: "this procedure does X" and it's crystal-clear from the code.

#### Refactor Arrow Code

Jeff Atwood has an excellent article titled [Flattening Arrow Code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). If your code looks like this:

```
If ...
    If ...
        If...
            For ...
               For ...
                   If ...
                       ...
                   End If
               Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End If
```

...you have *arrow code*. There are known, documented techniques to genuinely enhance such code, and `'~~~~~~BANNER COMMENTS~~~~~` aren't one of them.

1. Replace conditions with guard clauses.

   ```
   If SomeImportantCondition Then
       'procedure body
   End If
   ```

   Becomes:

   ```
   If Not SomeImportantCondition Then Exit Sub / Err.Raise ...
   'procedure body
   ```
2. Extract conditional blocks into their own scope.
3. Invert conditions to reduce nesting.
4. Return/exit early if you can.

The goal is to reduce horizontal scrolling as much as possible, and to reduce **nesting** and **cyclomatic complexity** - which are **real, measurable metrics** that can be acted upon.

[image: Rubberduck code metrics]

Comments are for saying *why*, not *what*. Let the code say *what*.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no function in the VBA editor to match ***if*** and the closing ***endif***.
I use Rubberduck, a free add-on to VBA. With it you can easily indent your code and make it more readable.

Before:

```
Option Explicit

Function test(a As Integer)
Dim b As Integer

    b = 1
     If a > 1 Then
   b = 2
    If a > 21 Then
b = 3
Else
b = 4
    End If
       End If
    test = b
End Function
```

After processed by Rubberduck:

```
Option Explicit

Function test(a As Integer)
    Dim b As Integer

    b = 1
    If a > 1 Then
        b = 2
        If a > 21 Then
            b = 3
        Else
            b = 4
        End If
    End If
    test = b
End Function
```

It can do much more than that too. 
You can download it here: http://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: b can never be 2 ;) . Rubberduck is a nice tool in any case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no marking function per se.
Use the Comment Function with the apostrophe to make sections

eg

```
'~~~~~PRINT FILE~~~~~~

'~~~~~CLOSE~~~~~~
```

etc

Comment: Whenever you add a comment like this, you've missed an opportunity to pull code into smaller, more specialized procedures that do less and have fewer reasons to fail.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Isn't there still a place for it, though? I mark small sections of code like this if I inserted it for test purposes (randomizing data, for example), to make sure it's easier to pull non-production code out later.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree with you there. I guess I was referring to the applicability of the commenting technique more than the contents.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt ok I'll try to be clearer: "banner comments" say *what*, not *why* - they are *by definition* bad comments, they distract from the code and scream "my procedure is doing too many things".